# How to separate an array from a command using quotes instead of spaces in bash

Tags: arrays, json, string, bash

I am currently writing a Bash script to search through a JSONL file of Mario Maker level data (found in this Reddit post https://www.reddit.com/r/MarioMaker/comments/wlkwp9/easily_searchable_database_of_super_mario_maker_1/) and print the level id, name of the course, and name of the creator. I am however running into a problem when trying to print all this found information out, as the arrays I'm getting are separated using spaces in the course names instead of new lines or quotes. Below is my current code, the Python script used to convert the id's to in-game id's, and a single entry in the JSONL file (it's over 16gb of raw text)

Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ids=$(grep $1 /path/to/file/courses.jsonl | awk -F ',' '{print $1}' | awk -F ':' '{print $2}')
cns=$(grep $1 /path/to/file/courses.jsonl | awk -F ',' '{print $5}' | awk -F ':' '{print $2}')
crs=$(grep $1 /path/to/file/courses.jsonl | awk -F ',' '{print $7}' | awk -F ':' '{print $2}')
for id in $ids; do
        idn=$(python3 /path/to/file/mmid.py $id)
        ida+=($idn)
done

for i in "${!ida[@]}"; do
        printf "ID: %s\n" "${ida[i]}"
        printf "Course Name: %s\n" "${cns[i]}"
        printf "Creator Name: %s\n" "${crs[i]}"
        printf "\n"
done
```

Python Script (code mostly taken from the above Reddit thread)

```
import struct
import hashlib
import hmac
import sys
idno = int(sys.argv[1])
key = hashlib.md5(b"9f2b4678").digest()
data = struct.pack("<Q", idno)
checksum = hmac.HMAC(key, data, 'md5').digest()
checksum = checksum[3:1:-1].hex().upper()
idstring = str.upper(hex(idno))[2:]
for y in range(8 - len(idstring)):
    idstring = '0' + str(idstring)
code = str(checksum) + '0000' + str(idstring)
print(code)
```

Example Entry from courses.jsonl

```
{"id":66782542,"retrieval_date":"2021-06-02T02:40:10.837452Z","url":"https://d2sno3mhmk1ekx.cloudfront.net/10.WUP_AMAJ_datastore/ds/1/data/00066782542-00001?Expires=1625193610&Signature=vh50sqvoN2u-Xu~uT2pYJMNzj1kV11NDt77BDC2UM5o9VtTz-3HNxheiWc~PxDJhCqDNL-M7u9qrFnQ6FkOxDTyzo3QrK1VcNDqoAFRKA2RL03au-FdN9daY4~CDeKS3TvEkpzqBGe9fZfwlz6S-z7~VwRLsjPbw26QSkeszZOdGNT75RWyx2jeqKYpcjzi4tagbiWwq0DzbHzaXjlIpYpTsHIPaemS0fpad0d-Hgv56R-c3BCt2rzCoxco~jpVO2FW2HZoQRJIPU0mwbZE0wLlpKEHMwEcOoUbRIbYP~5U4XFwc6eahHc19GRjttzNDHBm68u9yhi3BVjlaMnRm2g__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJUYKVK3BE6ZPNZBQ","stars":1,"course_name":"go","creator":{"pid":1753458969,"nnid":"Khanna1974","mii_data":"QlBGQwAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAwAAQLAAeGTApABA1vjUsH+qXdiADAAAcxVNAGEAcgBpAAAATQBFAAAAAAAAAEBAAACDAUJoRBggNEYUgRIBaA0AACkAUiVBTQBhAHIAaQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAI1HAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAE="},"upload_time":"2019-08-19T19:53:26Z","user_plays":17,"clears":14,"total_attempts":27,"failures":13,"world_record":{"best_time_player":{"pid":1744579894,"nnid":"HifysWU","mii_data":"QlBGQwAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAQMlEqo2ExqEA13Ajt2LjAh1dDQAAACBSAGEAdgBnAHoAAABFAAAAAAAAAH8oJgAiAIhGgxgTEoYUaxATZG0AACWCUUhQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGCXAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAE="},"first_complete_player":{"pid":1744078322,"nnid":"hellodarknessyee","mii_data":"QlBGQwAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAQPB5NCID5WIC2Pb9Wi0zXBWf6gAAARRSAG8AcwBlAAAATQBFAAAAAAAAAEBAMgCBBaBoYxKzMoUOoQwTZgwAKCG4OUhQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGK9AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAE="},"best_time_ms":5129,"created_time":"2019-08-19T20:02:41Z","updated_time":"2019-08-20T18:41:32Z"}}
```

So far I have tried using a loop and appending the data to a new array, and using `eval` to do basically the same thing.

Comment: `grep | awk | awk`, really ? oO Use `jq` instead.

Comment: yea imma be real, im barely learning bash as part of a cybersecurity class, so i dont know a lot of the optimal stuff

Comment: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: Why are you using Bash + Python instead of just Python? Python has JSON parsing in its standard library, and Bash is a terrible language for anything more complicated than gluing other programs together (and it’s not very good at that either).

Comment: you got a point yea. i think ill see if i get a better answer on the other question, or see if the python answer gets a little clarified so i can understand what im looking at. but thank you for all the help!

Comment: If you're learning bash as part of a cybersecurity class then you REALLY need to focus on the details to avoid potential security issues. Regarding "So far i have tried using a loop and appending the data to a new array, and using eval to do basically the same thing." - that's not necessary even if you were to do this part in bash and it's likely to introduce a code injection vulnerability, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048.

Comment: Something like this: https://gist.github.com/minitech/610850ea303d8835d67df1a0e3377749

Comment: Bash (and similar languages) and cybersecurity are not compatible things.  Almost all Bash programs start with a line that means the caller can make them do anything by just setting an environment variable, and then get worse from there.  It is very difficult to write shell programs that will not do something bad when they encounter slightly unusual inputs.  Explicit `eval` is bad, but Bash has at least 10 features that `eval` input data internally.  Writing shell programs that cannot be subverted by knowledgeable users (co-workers, fellow students, attackers, ...) is effectively impossible.

Comment: i am learning bash as part of the offensive side of cybersecurity, not the defensive side. stuff like automating searching databases and such.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do using `jq`:

```
jq -r '"ID: \(.id)
Course name: \(.course_name)
Creator name: \(.creator.nnid)"' file.json
```

Yields:

```
ID: 66782542
Course name: go
Creator name: Khanna1974
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the JSON and Python out of this as your question is about bash arrays and so those are just muddying things as you wouldn't have bash arrays involved in processing JSON with python.

So your current script basically looks like:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ids=$(printf '%s\n' 123 97 512)
cns=$(printf '%s\n' "This Is First" "Second Here" "And Third")
crs=$(printf '%s\n' "Joe Shmo" "Sue Me" "Perry The Platypus")

for id in $ids; do
        ida+=($id)
done

for i in "${!ida[@]}"; do
        printf 'i: <%s>\n' "$i"
        printf 'ID: <%s>\n' "${ida[i]}"
        printf 'Course Name: <%s>\n' "${cns[i]}"
        printf 'Creator Name: <%s>\n' "${crs[i]}"
        printf "\n"
done
```

and when executed it'll output:

```
$ ./tst.sh
i: <0>
ID: <123>
Course Name: <This Is First
Second Here
And Third>
Creator Name: <Joe Shmo
Sue Me
Perry The Platypus>

i: <1>
ID: <97>
Course Name: <>
Creator Name: <>

i: <2>
ID: <512>
Course Name: <>
Creator Name: <>
```

when what you want output is:

```
i: <0>
ID: <123>
Course Name: <This Is First>
Creator Name: <Joe Shmo>

i: <1>
ID: <97>
Course Name: <Second Here>
Creator Name: <Sue Me>

i: <2>
ID: <512>
Course Name: <And Third>
Creator Name: <Perry The Platypus>
```

That's because you're trying to access the contents of `cns` and `crs` by indexing them with the index from `ida[]`, e.g. `"${cns[i]}"`, but neither `cns` nor `crs` are arrays, they're strings, and so `cns[0]` is interpreted as just `cns` and so prints the whole `cns` string while `cns[any other index]` prints null. If you want them to be arrays then you could do:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readarray -t ids < <(printf '%s\n' 123 97 512)
readarray -t cns < <(printf '%s\n' "This Is First" "Second Here" "And Third")
readarray -t crs < <(printf '%s\n' "Joe Shmo" "Sue Me" "Perry The Platypus")

for i in "${!ids[@]}"; do
        printf 'i: <%s>\n' "$i"
        printf 'ID: <%s>\n' "${ids[i]}"
        printf 'Course Name: <%s>\n' "${cns[i]}"
        printf 'Creator Name: <%s>\n' "${crs[i]}"
        printf "\n"
done
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
i: <0>
ID: <123>
Course Name: <This Is First>
Creator Name: <Joe Shmo>

i: <1>
ID: <97>
Course Name: <Second Here>
Creator Name: <Sue Me>

i: <2>
ID: <512>
Course Name: <And Third>
Creator Name: <Perry The Platypus>
```

Now let's apply that to your real starting point which is you have some input text that you want to select some parts of for further processing, e.g. let's say you have CSV like:

```
$ cat input.csv
123,foo,This Is First,bar,Joe Shmo,other stuff
50,foo,To be Ignored,bar,Griffin,more stuff
97,foo,Second Here,bar,Sue Me,bad stuff
17,foo,Also Ignored,bar,The Stranger,etc.
512,foo,And Third,bar,Perry The Platypus,Blah blah
```

and want to process 3 fields from every line that doesn't contain the string `Ignore`. Again ignoring the fact you wouldn't really use a bash script for this and we're just demonstrating how to use bash arrays, that'd look like:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

infile='input.csv'

readarray -t ids < <(awk -F',' '!/Ignore/{print $1}' "$infile")
readarray -t cns < <(awk -F',' '!/Ignore/{print $3}' "$infile")
readarray -t crs < <(awk -F',' '!/Ignore/{print $5}' "$infile")

for i in "${!ids[@]}"; do
        printf 'i: <%s>\n' "$i"
        printf 'ID: <%s>\n' "${ids[i]}"
        printf 'Course Name: <%s>\n' "${cns[i]}"
        printf 'Creator Name: <%s>\n' "${crs[i]}"
        printf "\n"
done
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
i: <0>
ID: <123>
Course Name: <This Is First>
Creator Name: <Joe Shmo>

i: <1>
ID: <97>
Course Name: <Second Here>
Creator Name: <Sue Me>

i: <2>
ID: <512>
Course Name: <And Third>
Creator Name: <Perry The Platypus>
```

but calling awk 3 times to do the same search of your input file 3 times printing 1 field at a time is wasteful and makes it hard to maintain your script if your search criteria changes so you'd really want to do the search once to get all the data and then use it as you like, e.g.:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

infile='input.csv'

readarray -t lines < <(
    awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} !/Ignore/{print $1, $3, $5}' "$infile"
)

readarray -t ids < <(printf '%s\n' "${lines[@]}" | cut -d, -f1)
readarray -t cns < <(printf '%s\n' "${lines[@]}" | cut -d, -f2)
readarray -t crs < <(printf '%s\n' "${lines[@]}" | cut -d, -f3)

for i in "${!ids[@]}"; do
        printf 'i: <%s>\n' "$i"
        printf 'ID: <%s>\n' "${ids[i]}"
        printf 'Course Name: <%s>\n' "${cns[i]}"
        printf 'Creator Name: <%s>\n' "${crs[i]}"
        printf "\n"
done
```

or [less efficiently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice):

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

infile='input.csv'

readarray -t lines < <(
    awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} !/Ignore/{print $1, $3, $5}' "$infile"
)

while IFS=',' read -r id cn cr; do
    ids+=( "$id" )
    cns+=( "$cn" )
    crs+=( "$cr" )
done < <(printf '%s\n' "${lines[@]}")

for i in "${!ids[@]}"; do
        printf 'i: <%s>\n' "$i"
        printf 'ID: <%s>\n' "${ids[i]}"
        printf 'Course Name: <%s>\n' "${cns[i]}"
        printf 'Creator Name: <%s>\n' "${crs[i]}"
        printf "\n"
done
```

but of course if you just needed to do something in bash with the `id`, `cn`, and `cr` values such as call some other tool with them as arguments/input (represented by a function `prtVals()` below), you could actually just do either of these instead:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

infile='input.csv'

prtVals() {
        printf 'ID: <%s>\n' "$1"
        printf 'Course Name: <%s>\n' "$2"
        printf 'Creator Name: <%s>\n' "$3"
        printf "\n"
}

while IFS=',' read -r id cn cr; do
        prtVals "$id" "$cn" "$cr"
done < <(
    awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} !/Ignore/{print $1, $3, $5}' "$infile"
)
```

or:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

infile='input.csv'

prtVals() {
        printf 'ID: <%s>\n' "$1"
        printf 'Course Name: <%s>\n' "$2"
        printf 'Creator Name: <%s>\n' "$3"
        printf "\n"
}

while IFS=',' read -r -a line; do
        prtVals "${line[@]}"
done < <(
    awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} !/Ignore/{print $1, $3, $5}' "$infile"
)
```

or:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

infile='input.csv'

prtVals() {
        printf 'ID: <%s>\n' "$1"
        printf 'Course Name: <%s>\n' "$2"
        printf 'Creator Name: <%s>\n' "$3"
        printf "\n"
}

export -f prtVals

awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=ORS=","} !/Ignore/{print $1, $3, $5}' "$infile" |
xargs -d ',' -n 3 bash -c 'prtVals "$@"' _
```

That last one requires GNU xargs for `-d`.

Comment: So parsing `JSON` with `awk` or `bash` is a good practice for you? No better way?

Comment: @GillesQuénot the question asked was "How to separate an array from a command using quotes instead of spaces in bash" and **that is what others with that question will search for/find in future**. The fact that the OP started with JSON and then called python is irrelevant which is why I said at the top of my answer "Let's take the JSON and Python out of this as your question is about bash arrays and so those are just muddying things as you wouldn't have bash arrays involved in processing JSON with python.". IMO you're focusing on the wrong thing.

Comment: Note also that no part of my answer parses JSON with awk or bash nor do I suggest that anyone do so.